# How to load Array values to jcombobox?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an array and want to load the values of the to a jcombobox. I'm designing the application using Netbeans.
i want something like this in c#

```
Combobox1.datasource=myarray;
```

I don't want something like this

```
JComboBox b = new JComboBox(bla bla);
```

because i'm designing the GUI using the palette.

Thanks.

Comment: `c#` tag is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the properties of the combo box in the netbeans properties editor you can set the model that is being used for it. Look at the options it presents for that model and one of them does what you are looking for.

Comment: Specifically, `comboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<MyDataType>(myArray));`

Comment: Yes, except he's trying to do it using the GUI editor rather than in code :)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't clear on whether he was only creating the JComboBox in the GUI editor and wanted to set its model in code, or wanted to both create and populate it in the editor.

Comment: The question is a bit vague on that, the "designing it using the palette" line makes me think he's in the GUI editor though.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly give array that contains values while creating `JComboBox` as -

```
 String[] strArray = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E"};
 JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(strArray);
```

All the values get loaded to combo box on its creation.

As you are creating JComboBox using Palette then you can edit the creation by using option -

- Select the JComboBox added to your frame or panel.
- Choose combo box component and select right click option as "**Customize Code..**"
- Here "Code Customizer" opened, choose first option from combo as "**Custom Creation**" from left side.
- Here you can add code as - `JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(strArray);` and clock on OK.
- Make sure your array contains value to avoid exceptions before creating JComboBox in code.

OR

If you do not wish to provide array on create in `new JComboBox();` then you can do

- Manually in code via this lines of code -

  String[] strAyyary = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
  DefaultComboBoxModel defaultComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(strAyyary);
  comboBox.setModel(defaultComboBoxModel);
- Using NetBeans Palette -

  - Select the JComboBox added to your frame or panel.
  - Choose combo box component and select right click option as "**Customize Code..**"
  - Here "Code Customizer" opened, choose option from second combo as "**Custom Property**" from left side.
  - Here you can add code as - `comboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(strAyyary));` and clock on OK.
  - Make sure your array contains value to avoid exceptions before creating JComboBox in code.

Thanks

Comment: The second half of the question specifically states that `new JComboBox` is not an acceptable solution.